# Moodledata on shared storage on AWS

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, shared-storage, moodle

I am in the process of setting up a simple Moodle cluster on AWS for production use. The plan is to use a loadblancer, two EC2 instances and a RDS.  I have worked extensively with Moodle before but have never set it up on AWS before.

I am a little bit confused about where to put my moodledata directory as I will need to read/write to this directory from multiple EC2 instances. I see that EFS is the best option but apparently it is not available in Frankfurt(which is the region I have to use). Will I have to use S3? Or are there better options out there?

Answer (score 1):

I have been running multiple load-balanced Moodle sites on the AWS environment for several years using a dedicated AWS EC2 instance as a NFS server for moodledata.

Note: I have recently tried using EFS to replace it, but find that with moodledata on EFS the site runs very slowly.